# Forum software for asp.net c# that I can integrate into my asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for free/open or closed forum software for asp.net.  Most of the ones I have found require PHP and MySql.

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: A forum software written in asp.net that I can integrate into my current asp.net project

Comment: @Earwicker - get off your high horse and soap box...  This is totally relevant just like any question on CMS type solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.yetanotherforum.net/ - Yet Another Forum is a pretty popular ASP.NET based forum package.

Comment: Yes. I looked at this one, but is it the only free one.

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna try "Jitbit AspNetForum" http://www.jitbit.com/asp-net-forum/ We used it for years and they have a free evaluation version (fully functional). It also received a good review from Scott Hanselman here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselmanForumsAspNetForumFromJitBit.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Codeplex has a few: [here](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=forum&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|)

Chad Moran mentioned a good one, but I will link to the c# open source forum where I found it (just because the web site is a nice one to know about)

[Yet Another Forum.net](http://www.csharpopensource.com/csharpforumcode.aspx)